# Scraping all pages of a paginated site in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I'm trying to scrape web data from a county website using VBA in Excel 2013.  I'm new to this, and feel like my code isn't even worth posting, but I was hoping that I could get some help with my general approach.

A sample search term has led me to the [following URL](https://pa_allegheny.uslandrecords.com/palr/controller?commandflag=searchByNameID&optflag=SearchCommand&county=pa003&userid=null&userCategory=7&nameid=935708&partytype=&name=UNIVERSITY%2BPGH%2BTHE%2BCOMWTH%2BSYSTEM%2BHIGHER%2BEDUCATION&officeid=60&fromdate=01/01/1986&todate=04/14/2015&lastname=university)

If I click "Next", it takes me [here](https://pa_allegheny.uslandrecords.com/palr/controller?commandflag=searchByNameID&optflag=SearchCommand&county=pa003&userid=null&userCategory=7&nameid=935708&startrow=21&startpage=1&lastpage=10&partytype=&name=UNIVERSITY%2BPGH%2BTHE%2BCOMWTH%2BSYSTEM%2BHIGHER%2BEDUCATION&officeid=60&fromdate=01/01/1986&todate=04/14/2015&lastname=university)

I am limited to 20 search results at a time, and it looks like the "Next" button will take me to a similar URL, but with the "&startrow=" parameter set to 20 greater than the previous page.

If I want to copy all of the data from all pages, do I need to focus on "&startrow=" in order to properly loop?  And if so, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would loop and scrape until I don't find the `Next` button anymore, which means:

```
buttonFound = True '<-- False if we don't find --> break the loop
While buttonFound '<-- while we have a "Next" button

'scrape data then click next

Set allLinks = ie.getElementsByTagName("a")
buttonFound = False
For Each btn In allLinks '<-- search the button
    If btn.innerText = "Next"
        buttonFound = True '<-- if you find it, you will have to look for it next time
        Set btnNext = btn
        Exit For
    End If
Next btn

btn.Click '<-- go to next page and try again
Wend
```

I wouldn't rely too much on the URL as it might contain underlying logics from the back-end; rather, approach the problem as a front-end user (i.e. as long as I see the "Next" button, I click on it and I scrape the other page).

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try to integrate this into my code.