# VBA scraping - only reading first row in table

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to scrape an online table of springs into an Excel sheet. I adapted some online code to locate, read and paste the rows within the table into excel, however the program is only reading the first row (headers) from this table.

Table (https://www.leespring.com/compression-springs)

My assumption is the table headers and data rows are separate bodies within the table, so only the first is being read, but I have not found any way to specify that I only want data from the data rows. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub testing()
    Const URL = "https://www.leespring.com/compression-springs"
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    
    ' get web page
    Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    ' parse html table
    Dim wb As Workbook, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim tbl As Object, t As Object, tr As Object, td As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("cols-27") 'table being read
    
    If tbl(0) Is Nothing Then    'tbl(0) is the only table in this sheet
        MsgBox "No tables found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        r = 1
        For Each tr In tbl(0).Rows
            c = 1
            For Each td In tr.Cells
                Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The HTML code contains only the header - the rest is loaded dynamically and is not present in `HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML`.

Comment: Dang, does that mean that there is no way to scrape the table data using VBA?

Comment: You could try using the Selenium driver. But you will also have to find a way to deal with pagination (the web page shows always only a limited number of rows), and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661730/8422953